# How to extract but keep together items from list within list nested within another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to only extract the respective second items of lists within a list within another list. I want these to remain in their lists.

So far I've managed to return a list with all the values I want. However, the values aren't separated into their original lists anymore.

```
my_list = ([[1,2],[3,4]] , [[5,6],[7,8]] , [[9,10],[11,12]])

new_list = []

for i in range(1):
    for j in my_list:
        for h in j:
            new_list.append(h[1])

print(new_list)
```

Which results in:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

The output I want is this:

```
[[2,4] , [6,8] , [10,12]]
```

so that the respective items would still be together in their original list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

```
>>> new_list = [[y[1] for y in x] for x in my_list]
>>> new_list
[[2, 4], [6, 8], [10, 12]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. In the case of lists within lists that are long and of unequal length, is there a way to circumvent having to individually write down all the x[...][1] items in the list comprehension? , i.e. instead of [[x[0][1], x[1][1], x[2][1], x[3][1], (...) for x in my_list] ?

Comment: Assuming, all the list have two elements I have updated my answer. @Bella12345

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a list comprehension (although it is neater), so here is a working example just using for loops. You were very close, you just needed to append your items into lists which you then appended into a big list! :-)

```py
my_list = [[[1,2],[3,4]] , [[5,6], [7,8]] , [[9,10],[11,12]]]

result = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    result_sublist = []
    for item in sub_list:
        result_sublist.append(item[1])
    result.append(result_sublist )

print(result)
```